# Lightning Web Component Jest testing

Tags: unit-test, lightning-web-components, code-coverage, lwc-jest

Hi I am trying to test my child component from the Jest test for that I am trying to fire an event but I am getting an error.

Code In Jest:

```js
let aBCL = element.shadowRoot.querySelector(a-b-list-k');
aBCL.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('pass', { detail: { type: 'bgh', lenth: 5 } }));
```

The error I am getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null
```

Comment: Hi Riya: it seems that the problem is when the code tries to select the element `a-b-list-k`. Are you sure this is correct? Maybe you will have to provide us with the HTML structure in question. I also see that the `querySelector` seems to have a missing end of a string definition.

Comment: you also have a typo, right? a-b-list-k' with just one quote

Answer (score 1):

I think the comments to the question have answered this one, but I'll add an answer anyway to get this off the "Unanswered" queue.

The query for the element is invalid. Change:

```
let aBCL = element.shadowRoot.querySelector(a-b-list-k');
```

to

```
let aBCL = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('a-b-list-k');
```